# MSWord MailMerge OpenDataSource Excel Range issue

Tags: excel, vbscript, ms-word, mailmerge

I want to use VBScript to

1. open a Word document that already has merge fields
2. specify an Excel file and Named Range as the datasource
3. perform the merge

Code like the following Microsoft sample does not work in VBScript, which seems to hate the := construct.

```
With docNew.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource _
        Name:="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office" & _
        "\Samples\Northwind.mdb", _
        LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
        Connection:="TABLE Customers"
    MsgBox .DataSource.ConnectString
End With
```

To help track down the problem, I have tried the code as VBA inside a Word document, substituting the path to the Excel file for the sample's Access mdb file. But I can't seem to find the right thing to put as the Connection parameter. I have tried these:

```
Connection:="ExternalData_1"
Connection:="TABLE ExternalData_1"
Connection:="Sheet1$ExternalData_1"
Connection:="TABLE Sheet1$ExternalData_1"
```

By specifying the connection, I'm hoping to avoid the dialog box in the attached image file.[image: Dialog box]

Edit 8/2/2016
It made sense not to use a vbs script but instead vba in the Word template (mail merge "Main" document). So now my code looks like this:

```
With Me.MailMerge
    .MainDocumentType = wdFormLetters
    .OpenDataSource Name:=sPath & XLSM, Connection:="SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", ReadOnly:=True, LinkToSource:=False, AddToRecentFiles:=False
End With
```

I have used both [Sheet1$] and [Sheet1$ExternalData_1] without success.

At this point, being presented the dialog box shown in the image is such a trivial problem that I'm no longer trying to solve it. Too bad, though, that the answer is so elusive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript does not allow named parameters, so you have to use a construct more like this:

```
.OpenDataSource _
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office" & _
  "\Samples\Northwind.mdb",,,, _
  True, False,,,,,, _
  "TABLE Customers"
```

How to specify the parameters for .OpenDataSource varies quite a lot depending on the type of data source (e.g. an Access database, a text file, an Excel workbook, an Oracle database) *and* how you connect to that source (e.g. using a Word file converter, DDE, ODBC, OLEDB. A connection parameter such as "TABLE Customers" only works (AFAIK) for an Access table, and was originally used for a DDE connection (the original default connection type for Access databases). These days, most connections are made via OLE DB, and typically you need to specify a SQL statement. You can also omit the connection parameter for an Excel sheet. Incidentally, I don't think the LinkToSource parameter will do anything in this case either.

So what you need is more like this (There's 1 more comma after "False"):

```
.OpenDataSource _
  "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office" & _
  "\Samples\yourxlfile.xls",,,, _
  True, False,,,,,,, _
  "SELECT * FROM `Sheet1$ExternalData_1`"
```

Word itself inserts "backtick" characters (UNICODE U+0060 GRAVE ACCENT) around the sheet/table name but you should be able to use

```
  "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$ExternalData_1]"
```

if you prefer.

If the data source is a sheet name such as "mysheet", you have to append a "$". It is probably worth pointing out that not all named ranges are presented by the OLE DB provider (or ODBC driver) as data sources. In particular, you might hope that a table inserted using the various Data import options on the Data tab would be available, but they are not. Also, some named ranges are only available as data sources when the workbook is already open in Excel.

Comment: It made sense not to use a vba file, but rather to move the code into the Word template (mail merge main document). So now I'm using this code:

Comment: Sorry, I mistakenly put my comment here and then also in an edit to myu original post. That's where the code is.

Comment: OK, well assuming  the sPath & XLSM part is correct, the remaining problem is that the SQL parameter needs to be called SqlStatement instead of Connection

Comment: That indeed eliminated the unwanted dialog box.